# Remove table border for previous row based on current row in html and css

Tags: html, css

I have table as below and for certain rows class noBorder is applied which will romove top border for that row. Even though i remove border-top for current row, the previous(above)row border-bottom is visible. So based on class="noBorder" identifier, I should remove the above row border-bottom. How i can achieve that. The table will be generated dynamically from backend. After table generation i need to apply css style 2.1(not css3) for table modification.

**HTML:**

```css
.table-content > th,
.table-content td {
  border: black solid thin;
}

tr.noBorder td {
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%" class="table-content table-content4td lineHeight table-hideColumn3Border">
  <tr class="table-th-color">
    <td style="width: 5%" class="textAlignLeft">No.</td>
    <td style="width: 60%" class="textAlignLeft">Description</td>
    <td style="width: 20%" class="textAlignLeft"></td>
    <td style="width: 15%" class="textAlignLeft">Value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Row 1</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="noBorder">
    <td></td>
    <td>Test1</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Row2</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="noBorder">
    <td></td>
    <td>Test2</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Row 3</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Row 4</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="noBorder">
    <td></td>
    <td>Test 4</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>Row 5</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Value</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**The table is dynamic**, the row which has class noBorder will be added sometime only. So if that row present only, i have to remove top border of current row and bottom border of above row, else no need to remove any border.

Comment: not possible with only CSS , AFAIK

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix: add the `noBorder` class to the row which shouldn't have a *bottom* border. Then

```
tr.noBorder td {
  border-bottom: none;
}

tr.noBorder + tr td {
  border-top: none;
}
```

Adjust as needed

You may also be able to use `border-collapse: collapse;`, but it's not clear if that would cause other problems for you, e.g. with left and right borders.

Comment: The table is dynamic, the row which has class noBorder will be added sometime only. So if that row present only, i have to remove top border of current row and bottom border of above row, else no need to remove any border

Answer (score 1):

A better approach is to let the Table Cells `td` have only one border, ex `border-top`.

Add class for last child `:nth-last-child(1)` to have `border-bottom`.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ycdqdcj7/)**

```
.table-content td {
  border-top: black solid thin;
}

.table-content tr:nth-last-child(1) td {
    border-bottom: black solid thin;
}

tr.noBorder td {
  border-top: none;
}
```

Comment: I guess your suggestion is good, but i need to use css2.1 not css3. nth-last-child is in css3.

Comment: I think that doesn't solve the problem. The left and right borders should still exist. Even if you add them, the result is not like expected. The expected result should be like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ycdqdcj7/1/

Comment: Yes you are right, left and right border is required.

Answer (score 1):

You could do that is using some javascript.

You just get all the table's `td` child array, walks through that array and check if it has the class `noBorder`. If it has, add some other css class (could be `.noBottomBorder`) to the previous `td` wich removes the bottom border.

To get the child you run:

```
var tds = document.getElementById("mytableid").getElementsByTagName("td");
```

Comment: If i cant achieve this using html and css2.1, then i have to go for javascript only. But i have some limitation to use javascript.